# syntax error on varbinary(-1)

Tags: mysql, sql

I am receiving a syntax error:

> MySQL said: Documentation `#1064` - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
>   corresponds to your MySQL server
>   version for the right syntax to use
>   near '-1) NULL,   PRIMARY KEY
>   (diagram_id),   UNIQUE INDEX
>   UK_principal_name (p' at line 6

This is what i am trying to run. i have looked that the lines it is telling me is incorrect and i have yet to find the correct syntax to use. any help would be appreciated.

```
    DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `teamfocus_dbo`.`sysdiagrams`;
CREATE TABLE `teamfocus_dbo`.`sysdiagrams` (
  `name` VARCHAR(128) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci NOT NULL,
  `principal_id` INT(10) NOT NULL,
  `diagram_id` INT(10) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `version` INT(10) NULL,
  `definition` VARBINARY(-1) NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`diagram_id`),
  UNIQUE INDEX `UK_principal_name` (`principal_id`, `name`)
)
ENGINE = INNODB;
```

Comment: I suggest you format you SQL in a more readable way - this will also help you spot the syntax error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try changing the `VARBINARY(-1)` to a positive length, like `VARBINARY(1)`

Answer (score 0):

Pretty sure you can't have negative length columns... change VARBINARY(-1) to a positive length.

Maybe you're meaning to set the *default value* to -1?

```
`definition` VARBINARY(1) NULL DEFAULT -1
```

Comment: "VARBINARY(-1) to a positive length, like VARBINARY(1)" worked but the [code]`definition` VARBINARY(1) NULL DEFAULT -1
[/code] didnt.  i am not sure if it suppose to be set to -1 or not. i am taking a database i didn't create from MS SQL to MYSQL. but it all seams good now. Thanks for the help.